# After calling a function to retrieve JSON using URLSession, my array returns empty

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, urlsession

I am retrieving data in JSON format from a URL using URLSession. After decoding the JSON data, I print it for debugging reasons and also populate an array of struct CVE. The array has data, while inside the function jsonDataRequest, but when I try to get its elements from the ViewController, the array is empty. I searched for quite sometime on how to resolve it, but I am a bit stuck. Below is my code:

Inside the class, I have the following code:
The structure

```
struct CVE : Decodable
    {
        var CVE : String
        var severity : String
        var cvss3_score : String? = nil
        var public_date : String
        var bugzilla_description : String
        
    }
    struct CVEdata : Decodable
    {
        var cves : [CVE]
    }
```

The array I want to use from the ViewController

```
var arrCVE : [CVE] = []
```

The function I am calling from ViewController

```
func jsonDataRequest ()
    {
        let url = "https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata//cve.json?after=2022-12-26"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in
            do
            {
                // Json to Array
                self.jsonCVE = try JSONDecoder().decode([CVE].self, from: data!)
                
                var strCVE : String
                var strSeverity : String
                var strCvss3_score : String? = nil
                var strPublic_date : String
                var strBugzilla_description : String
                
                print(self.jsonCVE)
                for oCVE in self.jsonCVE
                {
                    print(oCVE.CVE + " " + oCVE.severity + " " + oCVE.public_date + " " + oCVE.bugzilla_description)
                    
                    // get each the CVE info
                    strCVE = oCVE.CVE
                    strSeverity = oCVE.severity
                    if (oCVE.cvss3_score != nil)
                    {
                        print(oCVE.cvss3_score!)
                        strCvss3_score = oCVE.cvss3_score
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("")
                        strCvss3_score = ""
                    }
                    strPublic_date = oCVE.public_date
                    strBugzilla_description = oCVE.bugzilla_description
                    
                    // save it to the array
                    self.arrCVE.append(CVE(CVE: strCVE, severity: strSeverity, cvss3_score: strCvss3_score, public_date: strPublic_date, bugzilla_description: strBugzilla_description))
                    print(self.arrCVE)
                }
               
                // Logic after response has arrived
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    print("main.async")
                }
            } catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

From the ViewController I instantiate an object from the class and access the array. I am displaying on a UITextView the array.count to see how many rows it contains

```
let oRedHatCVEs = RedHatCVEs()
oRedHatCVEs.jsonDataRequest()
txtvJSON.text = "Array elements: " + String(oRedHatCVEs.arrCVE.count)
```

and the result is **Array elements: 0**

Does it have to do with the asynchronous way the above code works? How can I finally get the array data back to my ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is to do with the asynchronous function `jsonDataRequest`.
There are many ways to deal (i.e wait) for asynchronous function to finish, before using the data.

This sample code shows one way using Swift async/await framework.
It also shortens the code to fetch the data.

```
 class RedHatCVEs {
     var arrCVE: [CVE] = []

     func jsonDataRequest() async {
         if let url = URL(string: "https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata/cve.json?after=2022-12-26") {
             do {
                 let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                 arrCVE = try JSONDecoder().decode([CVE].self, from: data)
             }
             catch {
                 print(error)
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
 let oRedHatCVEs = RedHatCVEs()
 Task {
     await oRedHatCVEs.jsonDataRequest()
     txtvJSON.text = "Array elements: " + String(oRedHatCVEs.arrCVE.count)
 }
```